# How can i override the overflow property in material UI MuiCard-root class

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, materialize, react-admin

This is my styles:

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  panel: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 10,
  },
  setLink: {
    display: 'inline',
    textDecoration: 'underline',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  },
  field: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  dropUp: {
    transform: `translateY(calc(-100% - ${theme.spacing(3)}px))`,
  },
});
```

But overflow is set to hidden on class `MuiCard-root`. how can I override that to visible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want to do with, but as the [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css) said:

*When the configuration variables aren't powerful enough, you can take advantage of the overrides key of the theme to potentially change every single style injected by Material-UI into the DOM. That's a really powerful feature.*

Here is an example:

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    // Style sheet name ⚛️
    MuiCard: {
      // Name of the rule
      root: {
        // Some CSS
        overflow: 'visible',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And you must wrap your component with:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
...
</ThemeProvider>
```

Check the snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ioq2z)

**EDIT**

Add a custom `className` to your component

```
<Card className={classes.customCardName}>
```

And in your styles add this

```
customCardName: {
    overflow: "visible"
  }
```

Comment: The project doesn't use createMuiTheme and ThemeProvider, It uses WithStyles.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox to see your example ?